# Install all packages from a folder with Ansible 2.0

Tags: find, ansible-2.x

I have a folder where I place unmaintained python packages, so I installed them from the zip rather than from their repository.

I am using Ansible 2.0, so the [find](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/find_module.html) command seems to be the way to do it

So far I was doing the following:

```
- name: Install unmaintained dependencies
  pip:
    name: "{{ my_project_app }}/requirements/{{ item }}"
    virtualenv: "{{ my_project_venv }}"
  with_items:
  - django-hijack-2.0.0.zip
  - django-image-cropping-django-19.zip
  - pisa-3.0.33.zip
```

Now I'm playing with the `find` command

```
- name: Loading unmaintained dependencies
  find:
   paths: "{{ my_project_app }}/requirements"
   patterns: "*.zip"
  register: unmaintained_dependencies

- debug:
   var: unmaintained_dependencies
```

If I run the playbook above, I get the following output

```
ok: [192.168.1.212] => {
    "files_found": {
        "changed": false,
        "examined": 3,
        "files": [
            {
                ...
                "path": "/data/my_project/requirements/pisa-3.0.33.zip",
                ...
            },
            ...
        ],
        "matched": 3,
        "msg": ""
    }
}
```

I guess that there must be a way to put everything together but here is where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't get what are you trying to achieve here yet.. Are you using the `find` module just because `pip` module doesn't install packages from zip files?

For your `find` workaround, you can create a task that iterates over the results of the `find` task, using `with_items: files_found.files`, and using `{{ item.path }}` whenever you need the path:

```
- name: Install unmaintained dependencies
  pip:
    name: "{{ item.path }}"
    virtualenv: "{{ my_project_venv }}"
  with_items: "{{files_found.files}}"
```

Also, instead of using `file`, you can try to make a loop using [`with_fileglob`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#id4):

```
- pip:
    name: {{ item }}
    virtualenv: "{{ my_project_venv }}"
  with_fileglob:
    - "{{ my_project_app }}"/requirements/*.zip
```

Note, I didn't have time to test any of these solutions, or to ask more about what were you trying to achieve, but I hope they help with your problem.

Comment: The first option solved my problem, I didn't know that accessing dicts was that obvious! I couldn't make it work using `with_fileglob` (correcting the minor quote misplacement in the answer) since it seems to work only for files hosted in the central machine, not in nodes.

Comment: `with_items: files_found.files` didn't work for me, had to do `with_items: "{{files_found.files}}"` .

Comment: Thanks @Richlv, I believe Ansible stopped allowing this syntax at some point. I've changed the answer.